# Phonegap: Check if vibrate/sound on touch is enabled on phone

Tags: android, ios, cordova, vibration

Is there anyway in a Phonegap app to check if the user has enabled vibrate or sound on touch? My client wants their Phonegap based app to have sound and vibrate on touch, but I only want it to happen when the phone actually has the settings enabled.

Is there a way to check this?

Comment: Do you even have to do that? I know natively on Android, this just happens by default, and you do not programmatically trigger haptic feedback. It would be weird if phonegap required you to.

Comment: @stevebot, not in webpages or webview Android does not add feedback.